# how to do the C++ typecast in case of the Function Pointers?

Tags: c++

```
//Function prototype        
Bus_MasterOS( Bus_Serial* serial_ctrl,
        callback_t response_cb,
        callback_param_t callback_param = nullptr,
        TIMERS_TD timeout ,
        uint16_t tx_size );

typedef void* callback_param_t;

typedef void callback_t( callback_param_t handle,
        uint8_t* data, uint16_t length, uint8_t error );

//Function call and the issue faces is here.            
Bus_MasterOS( Bus_Serial* serial_ct,
        nullptr/* issue is here, how to do the C++ style typecast to this value 'nullptr' */
                            ,reinterpret_cast<callback_param_t>(nullptr),
        1000U ,
        5U);
```

Comment: You don't need a cast. `nullptr` is implicitly convertible to any pointer type, including function pointers.

Comment: we need to do it to keep PC-lint quiet :(. That is the issue. Any solutions..

Comment: Get an updated version of PC-Lint? Preferably one that supports the C++11 standard?

Comment: Hi Cody, yes its the latest.

Comment: Classic case of turning a logistic problem into an engineering one. Escalate it to the management and don't give up, tools are supposed to help resolving problems, not to create ones.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `static_cast<callback_t*>(nullptr)` as in fact your prototype decays to

```
void Bus_MasterOS(Bus_Serial* serial_ctrl,
                  callback_t* response_cb,
                  callback_param_t callback_param,
                  TIMERS_TD timeout,
                  uint16_t tx_size);
```

Comment: Hi Jarod42, correct answer but i have used reinterpret_cast instead, as it involves pointer typecast! Please share your thoughts..